# primary key should be read only in django admin. But during new entry insert it should be visible

Tags: python, django

Hi i would like to make primary key as visible when viewing or modifying the records. But it should not be editable in django admin page. Hence i tried readonly_fields. How ever when i give read only, I am not able enter primary key value when i add new record.

Here is my admin.py

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        search_fields = ['name']
        list_display = ('name','id','dob','bill','mobile','email')
        list_filter = ('bill','proj')
        readonly_fields=('id',)
```

My model.py is ,

```
  class Employee(models.Model):
     id = models.IntegerField(max_length = 6,primary_key=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Of Birth')
     doj = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Of Joining')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class in admin.py should be like below. Please use `get_readonly_fields`  to do this.

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        search_fields = ['name']
        list_display = ('name','id','dob','bill','mobile','email')
        list_filter = ('bill','proj')
      # readonly_fields=('id',)

        def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            if obj: # editing an existing object
                return self.readonly_fields + ('id',)
            return self.readonly_fields
```